# What is smartresize() on isotope plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I try to use this:

```
$(window).smartresize(function(){


}).smartresize();
```

using isotope.pkgd.min.js but it say that "undefined is not a function". What the smartresize is?? I look at isotope source and there is no smartresize.

I'm asking what should I do to have smartresize() function for isotope plugin. It doesn't work when I include isotope.pkgd.min.js in my html.

Comment: You are using Bower for managing frontend libraries, like Isotope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (for isotope v1)

```
var $container = $('#container') // or whatever your ID is.
// initialize Isotope
$container.isotope({
// options... Add other options here
 resizable: false
});  

$(window).smartresize(function(){
$container.isotope();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The isotope package I have includes the smartresize from https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize in its source.  Have you tried adding that js to the page?